# Include folder not referenced by project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, webdeploy

I'm trying to figure out how to upload a folder that i do not want to reference in the project file. The folder "build" is and output step that is generated from webpack. I've found other threads with the same problem and this is what i've tried (added to the end of my pubxml file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="..\build\**\*" />

      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>build\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

which did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try "CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderFor**MSDeploy**DependsOn" instead of "CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderFor**Package**DependsOn".

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Based on my review of the latest MSDeployAddFilesOutsideOfProject.wpp.targets file (distributed with VS2015), "ForPackage" may be deprecated.  The target is still there but I can't find where its referenced.

**Update** - Wrote a quick blog post with more details:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/07/20/include-extra-files-in-webdeploy-package/